# Saving MATLAB figures as PDF with quality 300 DPI, centered

Tags: matlab, pdf, matlab-figure

I want to save a MATLAB figure as PDF, with quality 300 [DPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch), and centered.

So far I managed to save it, but the image appears cropped. I changed the page type to [A3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_216#A.2C_B.2C_C_comparison) and kind of solves the problem, but I am looking for something more elegant. I am doing it from the GUI, but maybe from the command line is easier in MATLAB.

Is there any package or script that makes this (fundamental task for publications and papers) a bit easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the following command:

`print -painters -dpdf -r300 test.pdf`

You will, of course, already have to have a file named test.pdf in the current directory.

Some notes on the -commands as well.

- -painters: this specifies the use of the painters alogrithm for the exporting.
- -dpdf: specifies a vector image, specially a pdf in this case.  This is through Ghostscript.
- -r300: specifies a 300 dpi resolution. -r400 would be 400 dpi and so on.

On an off note.  I tend to just save the figure as a high DPI tiff image and import that tiff into another program where I actually assemble my figure(s) for the paper.  I tend to lean towards CorelDraw personally.

Comment: Oh and it almost slipped my mind.  You might have to set paper position, paper position mode and paper orientation prior to printing if you end up not getting a centered image and such.  This would also allow you to format it to a greater extent if so desired.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to check the [`exportfig`](http://www.mathworks.ch/matlabcentral/fileexchange/727-exportfig) package

```
exportfig(gcf, path_to_file, 'format','pdf','Resolution', 300 )
```

also, you can check [`fig`](http://www.mathworks.ch/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30736-fig-the-exact-figure-size-and-no-white-space) package, which is nice to call before the `exportfig`:

```
figure
plot(x,y)
fig
exportfig(gcf, path_to_file, 'format','pdf','Resolution', 300 )
```